# PHP custom function with MySQL query not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, function

Ok here's the short hands on, i have custom function that runs 8 MySQL queries `SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE`. Now i have strict standards on so i had to remove error message each time i run query. So i did `error_reporting(0);` and next query then `error_reporting(-1)`

```
        $add_log = "INSERT INTO ac_cand_log
                        (
                            id,
                            action,
                            time
                        )
                      VALUES
                        {$var}";
        $error_reporting = error_reporting();
        error_reporting(0);
        MysqlFns::ExecuteQuery($add_log, "insert");
        error_reporting($error_reporting);
```

Now i am confused because i run the function and it does not produce necessary result for some reason. I am sure it run until the end. Does switching error reporting level can drive php/mysql nuts?

I also just imported backup database moments before it happened.
I know this happened to me before when i just started working on this project and imported database i could not trace why and then it stopped.

Basically i set `error_reporting(-1);` in all queries in function and put `die;` at the end  funny thing it showed strict standard warning and no other warnings for each query that executed however database was untact and when i refresh page all records was the same as before running query.

Can someone solve this mastery for me?

Comment: What standards force you to swallow error messages?  Sure, it isn't generally appropriate to display them directly to the user, but you should be logging them!  You should also be appropriately be handling exceptions as they occur.  Post what errors you are getting, so you can get useful assistance.

Comment: Hiding errors instead of fixing them is a really bad idea, it may lead to worse errors or problems.

Comment: Knowing the code for `MysqlFns::ExecuteQuery()` would be useful.

Comment: what's the content of `{$var}` ? unless it a concatenated string that contains three values separated by commas (id,action,time) - the `INSERT` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function like this

```
function skip($boolean = true) {
    if($boolean) {
         error_reporting(0);
    }
    else {
         error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    }
```

Before query,

```
skip(true);
#Query here#
```

after query, need to turn error_reporting to default

```
skip(false);
```

and if not useful, you need show your mysql function use to query

Comment: there is really no need to change the error reporting level during the script execution. As already posted by Brad in a previous comment, PHP errors should not be displayed to the user but be logged so that an admin will read them later and fix the problems.

Comment: @Jocelyn ye, but i dont know function MysqlFns::ExecuteQuery, so hiding error just temp solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a realy bad idea to ignore errors and warnings. If you don't want to show them to user, turn on log_errors directive and set error_log path in PHP.INI while disabling display_errors directive.

If you, for some reason, want to ignore errors, providing by function, try this:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) { }, E_ALL );
//your code
restore_error_handler();
```

But the better way is to fix your MySQL function - can you please give code or just this Strict Standarts error?

Comment: Ok strict standard error is triggered by MysqlFns**::**ExecuteQuery()

And just saying  Strict Standards: `Non-static method MysqlFns::ExecuteQuery() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/xxx/111/222/333/bbb/ccc/myclass.php on line 153`

the reason why it showing is because ExecuteQuery is in another class and i cannot use $this, its like notice so i would not think it does anything.

As i said i run with error_level -1 and had same issue.

Comment: that means, that you must instantiate your class before using it. Like $func = new MysqlFns(); $func->ExecuteQuery($add_log, "insert"); Or you can refactor your MysqlFns class to remove usage of non-static class vars and class instance and mark fucntion as static.

Answer (score 0):

With this Strict Standards below

> Non-static method MysqlFns::ExecuteQuery() should not be called
>   statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/xxx/111/222/333/bbb/ccc/myclass.php on line 153

you can try

```
$add_log = "INSERT INTO ac_cand_log
                (
                    id,
                    action,
                    time
                )
              VALUES
                {$var}";
$error_reporting = error_reporting();
error_reporting(0);
$Mysqlfns = new MysqlFns();
$Mysqlfns->ExecuteQuery($add_log, "insert");
error_reporting($error_reporting);
```

Because ExecuteQuery() is not static method, so you cannot call it as static method.